# Connect arduino pro mini 3.3v to 5v

Tags: arduino-pro-mini

Is it safe to run an arduino pro mini 3.3v by 5v?
I mean directly connect 5v to vcc not raw pin.

Comment: Have you examined the schematic yet?

Comment: Can you remove the voltage regulator? Just to be sure that it doesn't get reverse voltage.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

The only difference between the 3.3 V and 5 V Pro Mini is the crystal and the voltage regulator.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an 8 MHz resonator-clocked Promini will happily work at 5V vs 3.3V.

If you want, add a diode from VCC to the RAW pin to protect the regulator, altho it's [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005785A.pdf) does not indicate such is warranted.  Anecdotally, I used about 10 of these in my fencing club powered from 5V to the VCC line for quite a few years with no such protection and they ran fine for ~ 10 years, until we closed the club.